# Tracking down an error from gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, debugging

I'm seeing the following in my system log a couple of times per second:

```
Nov 10 17:01:21 madhatter gnome-shell[2949]: Object St.Button (0x55b4087421b0), has been already deallocated — impossible to get any property from it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Nov 10 17:01:21 madhatter gnome-shell[2949]: == Stack trace for context 0x55b3b9ddc5a0 ==
Nov 10 17:01:21 madhatter gnome-shell[2949]: #0   7ffc69950f60 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:695 (7fa33df71160 @ 15)
Nov 10 17:01:21 madhatter gnome-shell[2949]: #1   7ffc69951010 b   self-hosted:975 (7fa33de2e160 @ 392)
```

Neither the error message nor the stack trace is very informative. I'd appreciate suggestions on how to track down details regarding this error.